# mySQL: Counting TIMEDIFFs

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

so I got a table with ref_no's and datetimes.

What I want is the number(count) of ref_no's, where the time between each is a maximum of 30 minutes without any breaks over 30 mins between, so all sequences of consecutive times.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT  Y.ref, count(X.ref FROM Issue X INNER JOIN Issue Y ON X.ref=(Y.ref-1)
   WHERE '00:30:00' >=(SELECT TIMEDIFF((X.date),(Y.date)))
GROUP BY Y.ref
```

That delivers me all refs with a timedifference under 30m, but I can't manage to only get the datablock where no >30min break occurs.